# How can I turn off specific TSql warnings for files generated from a T4 template?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t4, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a T4 template that generates a lot of SQL code, for which I have lots of SQL71502 and SQL71562 warnings.

These warnings are expected and I want them ignored for that specific file.

I tried using the generated file properties to turn them off. It works, but the "Suppress TSql Warnings" property value gets cleared each time the template runs so it's pointless.

I don't want to disable these warnings on the whole project and the `pragma` instruction isn't supported AFAIK.

So far my only option seems to be using EnvDTE api, which I'd very much like to avoid.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

How about putting them all in a separate project and disabling the warnings there and using "same database" references to the main project (would be hard if you reference the generated objects and back to the main project)

Otherwise the dte api, it isn't that hard to enumerate all project items and check the properties I can point to a sample if you need one.

Ed

Comment: I can't do that. Some procedures depends on the generated code. I won't be able to both refer project A to B and B to A. As for the DTE api thanks for the offer but I already know how to use it. I just hate relying on it because it makes the solution depends on a plugin that must be installed on the side.

Comment: You know it is only xml in the project file (<ItemGroup><Build ..><SupressTSqlWarnings>1234) you could just write a powershell script or something - 2 things though if the user hasn't saved the project you will lose changes and they will get the annoying "project has changed do you want to reload" prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the tsql warnings on a per file basis in the properties dialog of the specific file:
[image: suppress-tsql-warnings-file-property]